# Navigation highlighting home when I'm on a subroute e.g blog/post in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

I have created a navigation component in Next JS and framer-motion to highlight the current page.

The problem is, when I'm on a sub route e.g 'localhost:3000/blog/post' the home tab will still be highlighted.

How do I only show the currently highlighted page and its subroute, e.g if you were on:

- localhost:3000/blog
- localhost:3000/blog/post

Only the blog tab would be highlighted

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import LogoText from './Logo';
import routes from '../routes/config';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContextProvider';
import Container from './Container';

const data = [
  {
    url: routes.home,
    name: 'Home',
  },
  {
    url: routes.dashboard,
    name: 'Dashboard',
  },
  {
    url: routes.cart,
    name: 'Cart',
  },
  {
    url: routes.blog,
    name: 'Blog',
  },
];

const Navbar = () => {
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { pathname } = router;
  const { logout, user } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pathname, 'test path');
    console.log(router, 'test router');
  });

  return (
    <nav className="">
      <div className="md:py-4">
        <Container>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-4">
            <div className="flex-shrink-0">
              <Link href={routes.home}>
                <a>
                  <LogoText />
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="font-bold md:block overflow-x-scroll md:overflow-x-visible">
              <div className="flex items-baseline space-x-4">
                {data.map((item, index) => {
                  const isSelected = pathname.startsWith(item.url);
                  return (
                    <Link key={index} href={item.url}>
                      <a
                        className={`${
                          isSelected
                            ? 'text-green-500'
                            : 'text-gray-300 hover:text-green-500'
                        } p-4 whitespace-nowrap relative`}
                      >
                        {isSelected && (
                          <motion.span
                            layoutId="underline"
                            className="absolute left-0 top-full block h-[3px] w-full bg-green-500"
                          />
                        )}
                        <span className="ml-1">{item.name}</span>
                      </a>
                    </Link>
                  );
                })}
                {user?.uid && (
                  <button onClick={() => logout()}>Logout</button>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**Update 1**

I tried Robert's suggestion:

```
      {data.map((item, index) => {

      const isSelected = path === routes.home || (path !== routes.home && path.startsWith(item.url))

       return (
          <Link
            key={index}
            href={item.url}
            className="text-gray-300 hover:text-green-500 p-4 whitespace-nowrap relative"
          >
            
            {isSelected && (<motion.span layoutId="underline" className='absolute left-0 top-full block h-[3px] w-full bg-green-500' />)}
            <span className="ml-1">{item.name}</span>
          </Link>
        )
      })}
```

works on the url '/blog' but not 'blog/sub-post'. On the latter type of route the home tab is also highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

This function determines the base path of a route from next.js useRouter hook

It splits based on the slash which is present in the URLs and takes the first entry which is the base path. This assumes your navbar has a base path and not an empty index route.

```
function getBaseRoute(route) {
  const paths = route.split('/').filter(Boolean);
  return `/${paths[0]}`;
}
```

Then we get the base route using the function and passing `pathname` from router

```
  const baseRoute = getBaseRoute(router.pathname);
```

Then you can proceed using the `baseRoute` string to compare it with the base path you want to highlight

```
        <li className={baseRoute === '/home' ? 'active' : ''}>
```

This will work on when you're viewing `/home` as well as any subpages `/home/update`

This is such an important feature, and the functionality above will fix your problems in your `navbar` component. I'm not sure about the behavior on index pages on route `/`.